# How do you create a list of all the words for which the first three letters are ‘the' with no duplication and sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a list of all the words in the file for which the first three letters are ‘the,’
disregarding case. That would include ‘the’, ‘thee’, and presumably others as well. No duplication in
what you print. To be clear, ‘the’, ‘The’, and ‘THE’ are the same word for purposes of this part. Sort
into alphabetical order

I am having a hard time successfully running the code. I am supposed to count every word in a long text sample that I have downloaded that starts with the letters 'the' and then sort them alphabetically.

def allWords (wordList):
    count = {}

```
for word in wordList:
    if word in wordList == 'the':
        ''.sorted(wordList) #to sort alphabetically

for wordList in words:           #so there are no duplicates 
    if allWords(wordList):
        if wordList not in shortList:
            shortList.append(wordList)
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried already

Comment: After posting your code, tell us what is the problem with it.

Comment: I am having a hard time successfully running the code. I am supposed to count every word in a long text sample that I have downloaded that starts with the letters 'the' and then sort them alphabetically. I apologize for any confusion, this is my first time on this site.

Comment: You can use `.lower()` and `.startswith()` to check if a string starts with a certain set of characters, and a `set` to force it not to have duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `set`to force not dups:

```py
words = ['therefore', 'THEREIS']  # etc

new_list = sorted(set(word for word in words if words.lower().startswith('the')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
l = ['therefore', 'THEREIS', 'Thereafter', 'THEY', 'THEASX', 'THY', 'THEEE', 'abcthe']

def allWords(wordList):
    return filter(myFunc, wordList)

def myFunc(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if ('the' in word and 'the' in word[:3]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

count = list(dict.fromkeys(sorted(allWords(l))))
for w in count:
    print(w)
```

Comment: Is there a way so the printed results do not print duplicates when I put a larger text file through the functions?

Comment: the list(dict.fromkeys()) should handle duplicates. I tried it with a duplicate string in l and it only included it once.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot